# Validating Char function

Tags: function, char, cin

SoI have to be able to validate the user input and make sure itis y or n for some reason it's not giving it to me and it is spamming the body of the while loop.. Please help.Thanks

```
char getCharChoice(string message, char y, char n)
{
char choice;

// Print the message and get the input
cout<<message<< " ";
cin>>choice;
// Check for valid input
while (choice != y || choice != n)
{

    cin.clear(); // reset the input stream
    cin.ignore(5000, '\n'); // take any remaining input off the stream

    // Ask for a choice and read user input
cout << "Not a valid input please: Choose y or n:  ";
    cin >> choice;
}


return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want "while (choice != y && choice != x)", the || made it a logical tautology.